# How to switch from one screen to another after a certain time in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, screen, swap

I'm new to ReactJS and want to implement the following logic: I have an intro screen in my app and after a few seconds I require to swap the intro screen with the home page.

How can I do this?

I have both the intro screen and home page in two separate components and I'm using React Router.

I've been thinking of using a `SetTimeOut` to change my components, but I don't know how to use it between components.

Here is my App.js code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Intro from './components/Intro';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Work from './components/Work';
import About from './components/About';
import Carrers from './components/Carrers';
import Contact from './components/Contact';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(){
   super()
 }

 render() {
 return (

   <React.Fragment>
     <Switch>
     <Intro path= "/" exact component={Intro}/>
     <Route path= "/home" exact component={Home} />
     <Route path= "/about" exact component={About} />
     <Route path= "/work" exact component={Work} />
     <Route path= "/carrers" exact component={Carrers} />
     <Route path= "/contact" exact component={Contact} />
     </Switch>
   </React.Fragment>
 );
 }
}


export default App;
```

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intro component can be like this

```
class Intro extends React.Component {


componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.props.history.push('/home')
    }, 5000) // render for 5 seconds and then push to home 
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>render for 5 seconds and then push to home</h1>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this question:
[Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Basically, you will get history from props and will use it to push to new route.

```
const { history } = this.props;
history.push('/new-location')
```

If you don't see it into your props because it's not the Component from your Route, you will need to use withRouter from 'react-router-dom'.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
export default withRouter(Component);
```